# can't install iis logging tools using the web platform installer 3.0

Tags: wordpress, iis-7.5, web-platform-installer

Trying to install WordPress from Web Platform Installer on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and having problem with one of its dependencies : IIS logging tools. Also tryed to install IIS Logging Tools from the Web Platform Installer and got no success. Se install log:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?        linkid=9767054
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767054 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:14:46 GMT
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:15:46 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 18:51:03 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1cada9b1418cd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 791313531200000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:15:46 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\542864071.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 13:43:26 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "fc283790fb1ecd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 279698231100000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:15:47 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1338951197.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Nov 2011 18:16:33 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "4bfbe4b5b9fcc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 279698231100000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:15:48 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\664384761.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/toolsproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/toolsproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Mon, 20 Feb 2012 22:27:49 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "49228ce01ef0cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 791790030800000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:15:48 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1956869252.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Tue, 11 Oct 2011 16:02:13 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "265bd232f88cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 7917131400000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:15:48 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\903079739.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 0, minorSP: 0, productType: 7, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:14:49 GMT
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:15:49 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Windows Cache Extension 1.1 for PHP 5.3 (WinCache53) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'WinCache53'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'StaticContent' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASProcessModel' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'DefaultDocument' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'DirectoryBrowse' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'HTTPErrors' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'HTTPLogging' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'LoggingTools' for product 'WinCache53'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'RequestMonitor' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'RequestFiltering' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'StaticContentCompression' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'IISManagementConsole' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASConfigurationAPI' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'CGI' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'UrlRewrite2' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'FastCGIUpdate' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'PHP53' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product FastCGIBackport does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'VC9Redist' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No SQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No MySQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting IIS 7.5 component install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Creating IIS 7.0 unattended setup file: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\216\tmpA8DB.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting IIS unattended setup: C:\Windows\sysnative\pkgmgr.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe' to: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\216\tmpA90B.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe"
Location: http://superb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe
Set-cookie: sf_mirror_attempt=wincache:superb-sea2:/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe; expires=Sat, 21-Apr-2012 02:18:25 GMT; Path=/
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:16:25 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.26


DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://superb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/0.6.39
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:16:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 161
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe?download&failedmirror=superb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net


DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe?download&failedmirror=superb-sea2.dl.sourceforge.net responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe"
Location: http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe
Set-cookie: sf_mirror_attempt=wincache:superb-sea2|iweb:/wincache/wincache-1.1.0/wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe; expires=Sat, 21-Apr-2012 02:18:26 GMT; Path=/
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 21 Apr 2012 02:16:26 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.26


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\216\tmpA90B.tmp' to: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WinCache53\5862B1955ACEE88B2BFA74E590A94D82F7464A9C\wincachewpi-1.1.0-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Waiting for process: 3360 - C:\Windows\sysnative\pkgmgr.exe
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Unattended setup returned '-2146498529'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Logging Tools done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Cache Extension 1.1 for PHP 5.3'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Cache Extension 1.1 for PHP 5.3 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Clearing cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product IIS: Logging Tools (LoggingTools) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'LoggingTools'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASProcessModel' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No SQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No MySQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting IIS 7.5 component install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Creating IIS 7.0 unattended setup file: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\216\tmpA264.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting IIS unattended setup: C:\Windows\sysnative\pkgmgr.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Waiting for process: 5060 - C:\Windows\sysnative\pkgmgr.exe
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Unattended setup returned '-2146498529'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Logging Tools done install completed
    DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! I had to install using server manager/roles/web server/Add role services. My machine is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. In W7 I believe is control/programs/turn windows features on or off.

Comment: This helped me.  Not necessarily for installing wordpress (as per OP) but I'm guessing this applies to many web platform installers on windows server... and they suggest it makes the process easier...

Comment: Yes! The key for me was that I was on Win 7 so had to enable CGI and logging under IIS in control/programs/windows features.